# Multiple Sums with different where clauses in same query result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join

I have a few tables that I am joining together and selecting various columns and sums from it and i want to combine the select statements so that all results are in the same results set. 
i currently have a query like:

```
declare @year INT
declare @month INT
set @year = '2013'
set @month = '08'

select CAST(LEFT(b.name, 3) AS varchar(3))AS Region, a.model, sum(a.Number)AS Uniques
from Table1 a
inner join database2.....table2 b
on a.code = b.code
where Year(a.EventDate) = @year
and Month(a.EventDate) = @month
and a.make='Toyota'
group by CAST(LEFT(b.name, 3) AS varchar(3)), a.model
order by CAST(LEFT(b.name, 3) AS varchar(3))
```

This brings up a dataset which looks something like:

```
Region   Model    Uniques
EST      Toyota      200
EST      Honda       350
CEN      Toyota      220
CEN       VW         150
```

I then have another similar query, but which uses different tables and requirements:

```
select CAST(LEFT(c.name, 3) AS varchar(3)) AS Region, a.Model, sum(b.Number)As Sales
from Table1 a
left join Table3 b
on a.leadid = b.leadid
inner join Database1..Table2 c
on a.code = c.code
where Year(a.EventDate) = @year
and Month(a.EventDate) = @month
and a.make='Toyota'
group by a.Model, CAST(LEFT(c.Name, 3) AS varchar(3))
order by CAST(LEFT(c.Name, 3) AS varchar(3))
```

this brings up a similar results set:

```
 Region      Model       Sales
    EST      Toyota      150
    CEN       VW         80
    CEN      Toyota      75
```

I just want to pair these results or make a joined query so I can have results like;

```
Region    Model       Uniques    Sales
EST       Toyota      200         150
EST       Honda       350          0
CEN       Toyota      220         75
CEN       vW          150         80
```

There are maybe 20-30 combinations of Region/Model that exist in total, and they are the same for each result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you cannot do it all in one query, then you can simply join the 2 queries together:

```
select
t1.region,
t1.model,
t1.uniques,
t2.sales
from
(select CAST(LEFT(b.name, 3) AS varchar(3))AS Region, a.model, sum(a.Number)AS Uniques
from Table1 a
inner join database2.....table2 b
on a.code = b.code
where Year(a.EventDate) = @year
and Month(a.EventDate) = @month
and a.make='Toyota'
group by CAST(LEFT(b.name, 3) AS varchar(3)), a.model
order by CAST(LEFT(b.name, 3) AS varchar(3))
) t1 
inner join
(
select CAST(LEFT(c.name, 3) AS varchar(3)) AS Region, a.Model, sum(b.Number)As Sales
from Table1 a
left join Table3 b
on a.leadid = b.leadid
inner join Database1..Table2 c
on a.code = c.code
where Year(a.EventDate) = @year
and Month(a.EventDate) = @month
and a.make='Toyota'
group by a.Model, CAST(LEFT(c.Name, 3) AS varchar(3))
order by CAST(LEFT(c.Name, 3) AS varchar(3))
) t2
on t1.region = t2.region 
and t1.model = t2.model
```

Comment: Thanks this answer works perfectly. I did this and then took out the ORDER BY from inside the original queries and got my results set.

Comment: +1, but it may need a `FULL JOIN` and NULL handling to get all results from both subqueries

Comment: Yeah I just did LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of inner join and then in my select statement was: SELECT t1.region, t1.model, t1.uniques, isnull(t2.sales,0) AS sales

Answer (score 3):

Use this concept:

```
SUM ( CASE WHEN ConditionIsMet THEN Column1 ELSE 0 END ),
SUM ( CASE WHEN OtherCondIsMet THEN Column2 ELSE 0 END )
```