# Multiple sum on different cols in same query

Tags: mysql, join, sum

Is it possible to sum on cols if inner join is true and sum on another cols if another inner join true?  i.e.

```
SELECT t1.debit 
     , t2.credit  
     , t1.ID 
     , t2.ID 
  FROM
     ( SELECT SUM(booking_value) debit 
            , gl_acct.id_fin_gl_acct ID 
         FROM bookings 
         JOIN gl_acct 
           ON (CONCAT('1',gl_acct.id_fin_gl_acct) = bookings.id_debit_account)
     ) t1 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT SUM(booking_value) credit 
            , gl_acct.id_fin_gl_acct ID 
         FROM bookings 
         JOIN gl_acct 
           ON (CONCAT('1',gl_acct.id_fin_gl_acct)=bookings.id_credit_account)
     ) t2
    ON (t1.ID = t2.ID)
 GROUP  
    BY t1.ID
```

Please explain your answer.

Comment: @spencer7593
i want to get sum all of debit and credit for each user i watch this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530617/multiple-sums-with-different-where-clauses-in-same-query-result-set)  and i wrote this query  i will post it in another comment

Comment: `SELECT t1.debit , t2.credit  ,  t1.ID , t2.ID FROM
(
SELECT sum(booking_value) as debit , gl_acct.id_fin_gl_acct  as ID from bookings INNER JOIN gl_acct on (CONCAT('1',gl_acct.id_fin_gl_acct)=bookings.id_debit_account)
)t1 INNER JOIN
(
SELECT sum(booking_value) as credit , gl_acct.id_fin_gl_acct as ID from bookings INNER JOIN gl_acct on (CONCAT('1',gl_acct.id_fin_gl_acct)=bookings.id_credit_account)
)t2
ON (t1.ID = t2.ID)
GROUP BY t1.ID`

Comment: I think this wins the prize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of conditional aggregation.

```
 SELECT t.id_account
      , SUM(IF(t.cr_or_db='cr',t.tot_booking_value,0)) AS `tot_credit` 
      , SUM(IF(t.cr_or_db='db',t.tot_booking_value,0)) AS `tot_debit`
   FROM ( 
          SELECT 'cr'                  AS `cr_or_db`
               , c.id_credit_account   AS `id_account`
               , SUM(c.booking_value)  AS `tot_booking_value`
            FROM bookings c
           GROUP BY c.id_credit_account
           UNION ALL
          SELECT 'db'                  AS `cr_or_db`
               , d.id_debit_account    AS `id_account`
               , SUM(d.booking_value)  AS `tot_booking_value`
            FROM bookings d
           GROUP BY d.id_debit_account
        ) t
  GROUP 
     BY t.id_account
```

The inline view `t` gets us total credits for each `id_credit_account` and total debits for each `id_debit_account`.

The original query joins both of those `id_` columns to the same account table, so we're assuming those are both foreign keys to that other table, which means they are the same datatype...

A join operation would only be required if there is some reason we need to include the `gl_acct` table. Assuming that `id_fin_gl_acct` is UNIQUE in `gl_acct`... we could add the join operation before the GROUP BY clause.

```
    ...   
        ) t

   JOIN gl_acct g
     ON CONCAT('1',g.id_fin_gl_acct) = t.id_account 

  GROUP 
     BY t.id_account
```

Comment: i make GROUP by before and it's return result but is not what i want because  inner join will skip rows that not equivalent id by the way thanks for your help and explanation ;)

Comment: @HussienAl-maani: Right. With the JOIN operation, you would only return rows where the `id_account` value appears on both sides. If an id is missing on one side or the other, rows will be excluded. Which is why I think you want to get the "total debits" and "total credits" separately. To get those combined, we can use a UNION ALL operation. To get the results for each id on a single row, we can reference the combined set as an inline view, and use a GROUP BY operation, and use conditional aggregation.

Comment: you give me a good example , explanation and solution  ,, **thanks** again for everything